# Discussion shouldn't be moved to chat

Tags: support

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/72645/35947

This is an important discussion that clarifies both the question and the answer and should be restored to the main page of the question.

Answer (score 5):

### If they provide necessary clarification, this should be edited *into the question and answer proper*.

Comments are temporarily by nature and if one wants to have information contained therein to be permanent, incorporation into posts is the way to go.

Comment: Why do you think FAQs is a common way to document things?

Comment: @d-b Q&A is the StackExchange way to document things. It is the very core idea of the network to have a database of questions and good, well-founded, and exhaustive answers.

Comment: Exactly. You can't apply the same standards for a question about programming and a question about philosophy. A programming question might be unclear on a certain detail that can be clarified by editing it. However, a philosophy question is much more vague and can't be clarified with a simple edit, instead it NEEDS a discussion back and forth. And often a consensus can't be reached so it is up to the reader to determine what(s)he thinks about the clarification. Hence, a discussion shouldn't be move to chat.

Comment: @d-b I am certainly aware of all that. But a) the discussion is still available even if in chat and b) it's not like the basic premises of the model of StackExchange were up to debate here. As several meta posts here point out, these tensions are the reason for this site not being the place for *doing* or *discussing* philosophy, but rather for asking and answering questions with rather precise scope and expectations.